# CSS: Position left: 250px, but overflow hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar which is shown and hidden by JS with css animations. For this, I need to position the content div (`#main`) with `left: 250px;`.

```
#main {
  left: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Inside the `#main`-div there is some content. For example a big table

```
<div id="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR
</div>
<div id="main">
    <table style="width: 100%" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>SOME BIG CONTENT1...</td>
            <td>SOME BIG CONTENT2...</td>
            <td>SOME BIG CONTENT3...</td>
            <td>SOME BIG CONTENT4...</td>
            <td>SOME BIG CONTENT5...</td>
            <td>SOME BIG CONTENT6...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My question/problem: How to prevent the horizontal scroll bar?

See https://jsfiddle.net/3y6hpeyw/

**EDIT: Solution of KCarnaille:**
See https://jsfiddle.net/3y6hpeyw/12/

The only problem with this, is the lack of support for older browser (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Comment: I would simply add `overflow:hidden;` to the body when the sidebar is open, since you're already doing that action with JS you can simply append a class to prevent overflow. Swap the table out for a list and make the web a better place.

Comment: If you are interested you can do something like this with flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/3y6hpeyw/4/

Comment: addin overflow:hidden to body doesn't work. And you do not understand - its an animated (and possible invisible) sidebar. So for transition, I need the left position. See updated example to see what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/3y6hpeyw/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, and it animates nice together with your sidebar.

Check out your [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3y6hpeyw/14/)

```
.sidebar-open #main {
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to #main :

```
 width: calc(100% - 250px);
```

It works with the fiddle you gave.

Comment: Nice solution. I just tried it with a more complex version (see new fiddle and it work as well). https://jsfiddle.net/3y6hpeyw/12/ . The only problem with this, is the lack of support for older browser.

Comment: Indeed ! The solution of LGSon is maybe a bit cleaner then.